# Move cursor within VMware

Tags: c#, console-application, vmware

OK, so I have been racking my brain on this for a while and I need some help. I have a small C# application that I have built and I want to move the cursor. Below is the following code snippet that "should" move the cursor:

```
Console.WriteLine("x::"+Cursor.Position.X+" y::"+Cursor.Position.Y);
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
Console.Read();
```

What is driving me nuts is that this works on my host Windows 7 machine but not on my Windows 7 my VMWare guest.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I've scoured the internet but haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you see instead?  Have you tried re-printing out the position after moving it to confirm the update?  Are you sure that subtracting 50 won't make either the X or Y position go negative?

Comment: You might be better off checking the VMWare support forum or asking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be an issue with VMWare tools. I uninstalled VMWare tools and it worked. I think it has something to do with the virtual mouse driver, however when I tried to re-install VMWare Tools without the mouse drivers it still did not work.

The only solution I found was to completely remove VMWare Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [InputSimulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/):

> The Windows Input Simulator provides a simple .NET (C#) interface to simulate Keyboard or Mouse input using the Win32 SendInput method. All of the Interop is done for you and there's a simple programming model for sending multiple keystrokes.

You'll need to reference it in your application and later copy it to the guest machine alongside your compiled executable .

Comment: thanks. That is a good library, however that won't solve my issue in this case as it had to do with VMWare tool and the need for elevated permissions.